# Using variables within patterns for sed -n command to extract last month's entries in a log file

Tags: bash, file, date, logging, sed

I've looked everywhere, but the only solutions I could find involved hard-coding in the dates, so aren't relevant to me.

I have a log file along these lines:

```
2018-01-31: Random string. 
2018-01-23: More text. 
2017-12-30: Some more text.
```

etc.

I wish to write a Bash script to extract last month's lines into a new file, e.g.:

```
2018-01-31: Random string. 
2018-01-23: More text.
```

The closest solution I could find was to use sed, e.g.:

```
sed -n '/Feb 23 13:55/,/Feb 23 14:00/p' file.txt
```

The problem is the dates are hard-coded (and in a different date format, but that's trivial). I need a solution that will work with a variable date, as the script will run via cron at the start of every month.

So, I came up with the following...

```
#Define date variables
DATEYYYY=$(date +"%Y")
DATEMM=$(date +"%m")
LASTYEAR=$(expr $DATEYYYY - 1)
LASTMONTH=$(expr $DATEMM - 1)

#Use only last month's update information.
if [[ $DATEMM -eq 1 ]]
then
    sed -n "/$LASTYEAR-12-01/,/$LASTYEAR-12-31/p" file.txt > file2.txt
else
    sed -n "/$DATEYYYY-$LASTMONTH-01/,/$DATEYYYY-$LASTMONTH-31/p" file.txt > file2.txt
fi
```

(Side-note: there needs to be a test in case the script is run in January, as that means the year number needs to be the previous year, hence the *if* statement. I would appreciate more elegant solutions to this as well, if any exist...).

The problem with the above is that the end result is an empty file2.txt, and I have no idea why.
I have looked at a variety of guides explaining how to use variables in sed, but I can't get my head around it.

Little help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't need the exception, the date command can do that work for you, so it becomes a one liner:

```
sed -n "/^$(date -d "last month" +%Y-%m)/p" file.txt > file2.txt
```

Note that I anchored the search to the beginning of the line "^" so anything starting with the matching YYYY-MM is output (as opposed to anything that might have that YYYY-MM in the text).

The reason your solution doesn't work is that it's trying to match everything line BETWEEN the matched starting date and the matched ending date, so 2018-01-01 must exist in the file and be prior to the line 2018-01-31 which also must exist (a problem for 2018-02-31) so rather than matching a range, mine matches each line.

Comment: Ahh ok, that explains that then! Thanks so much - your solution works perfectly. :)